# Place the rating bar?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing simple mail function. I've a list of mails from server. Now, i want to use rating bar for  notifying important mail. And, the star must have two function that when the star is enabled it'll set 1 to database and if it's disabled set 0 to database. Is there any possibilities for this method? Help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try customised checkbox button and its value to store in databse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<CheckBox
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>
```

and here is the fine [Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html)